# My profile modelform do not save to the database (Django)

Tags: django

I have two ModelForms. A UserForm and a ProfileForm. I don't know how to save the form data to the user objects profile.

This is how some of it looks in my post function inside my generic view:

```
user = user_form.save(commit=False)
profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)

password = user_form.cleaned_data['password']

user.set_password(password)
user.is_active = False
user.is_staff = True
user.save()
```

I tried saving the profile with:

```
about = profile_form.cleaned_data['about']
user.profile.about = about
```

But that didn't work. I got `User has no profile.` How do I save the data?

Comment: did you manage to sort this one out?

Answer (score 1):

But the profile itself isn't being saved at all!

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

> This save() method accepts an optional commit keyword argument, which
>   accepts either True or False. If you call save() with commit=False,
>   then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the
>   database. In this case, it’s up to you to call save() on the resulting
>   model instance.

While you are doing this for the user instance ,you are not calling save on the profile instance.